# Need background-color to fill space

Tags: html, css, angular8

My background-color attribute is not filling the space completely (see image)[image: Background not filling] (Image shows page content to right and top but background color does not fill the white space)

Here is what the code looks like:

```
<body style="background-color: #163a4b; color: white">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div style="margin: 15px">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #163a4b; color: white">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div style="margin: 15px">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just go `min-height: 100vh;` for your `body`.

Comment: Your posted snippet works — in that the `background-color` fills the whole background — for me.

Comment: The code works fine for me. Maybe some other CSS styling is interfering with your code?

Comment: I'll take a look around but keep in mind that it is a JS compiled body/component because it is part of an angular 8 application so that may have something to do with it. I'll take more of a look though.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I've looked into it quite a bit, messing around with the components and so on. I've figured out that it needs to be done in the index.html on the body element there instead of the component's body. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required addition is to do the background color on the index.html instead of the component's HTML. That'll solve the issue.

Before (app.component.html)

```
<body style="background-color: #163a4b; color: white">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div style="margin: 15px">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

After (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="background-color: #163a4b;">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```